# Rails app as backend for multiple apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We're developing a Rails app that will serve as a backend for multiple apps. The Rails app will have a web CMS that will let admin users to manage their mobile apps (one admin user can have 1..N mobile apps).

The same Rails app will also serve as an API for those mobile apps. The mobile apps are completely separated one from each others, not sharing any data among them. We have users with different roles (*global_admin* which manages his app in the CMS, *place_manager* which manages his place in the app within the CMS, and *users* of the mobile app). These users are not shared between apps (if a user signs up in a mobile app, he will be able to log in **only** in that app; so if he wants to log in another mobile app he needs to register again).

Which is the best approach to achieve this? We are thinking about:

- Option 1: we can have a single `User` model, with different roles on different apps (`global_admin` on app 1, `user` on app 2,  `manager` on app 3...). If a user signs up for app 1, a record is created, and if he signs up for app 2, we only add a role to it, but he *thinks* that he created a new account.
- Option 2: we can create a record for each user on each app (removing the uniqueness constraint on the email field)
- Option X: ideas?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do your mobile apps share the same API structure?

Comment: Yes, they are 100% equal

Answer (score 2):

The API/API users scenario looks like a situation for multi-tenancy in which each app runs as a separate instance. You can look at something like [Apartment](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) for database level multitenancy, or [Milia](https://github.com/dsaronin/milia) for app level multitenancy.

Database level is generally easier to manage, but you will need a workaround for the global admin requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following approach if you would like to use a single `rails` application for multiple mobile apps.

1. For `users` you can have different API returning different kinds of `users`, specific to the application requirement.
2. Use [STI](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Single+table+inheritance) to differentiate users for each apps(in this way, you could have only a single table for users but different models)

Comment: I don't know how STI will help us here, users should have different passwords, data, etc. in different apps, and they should be created dynamically

Answer (score 0):

> These users are not shared between apps (if a user signs up in a
>   mobile app, he will be able to log in only in that app; so if he wants
>   to log in another mobile app he needs to register again).

In my opinion these are three different Rails apps. Obviously the apps have nothing in common, in particular no data is shared.

Comment: Thank you for your response. True, but we need to keep all of them in the same Rails app to automate the creation of new mobile apps (our Rails app is a platform to create and manage different mobile apps).

Comment: You can have several Rails apps on the same machine. Would that maybe work for you?

Comment: That could work, but we **need** to keep everything within the same app

Comment: Could you list the requirements that make you believe that all apps must be in one Rails application? I think it is a better design to have the three applications coexist on the same machine. They can interact in the same OS if necessary, or you might simply have an appropriate API to let them interact with each other.

Comment: We want the admin users to create new apps dynamically. That's the major requirement

Comment: Why wouldn't that be possible in that scenario? I mean that requirement does not hinder you from having three separate Rails apps (they can interact with each other through OS, API, etc. you name it), does it? Maybe I am not getting it right, but please let me know.

Comment: With multiple Rails apps, a new Rails app should be created when an admin presses the "Create new app" button, and that would involve managing domains, DNSs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think Option 1 would work well in your case. You can setup a `has_many :through` relationship between `apps` and `users` that will contain information regarding the user's role for that particular application (assuming only one role per user per application).

With this approach the workflow would be a bit different than what you describe though. If the user is not registered at all (i.e. no record with that email exists), they will need to signup (email + password) at which point you'll create the user record (with hashed password) and setup the association to the mobile application. If the user *IS* already registered, you don't want them entering a new password again, you'll simply want to setup the association. This can be handled via [first_or_create](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that users of different apps should have different passwords, profile pictures, etc. (admin users know that they are on a platform that holds multiple mobile apps, but users of those mobile apps don't, they should think they are on an isolated app

Comment: Hmm I see. So how does the user decide which app they're logging into? Is there a single login form or will each mobile app have their own login form?

Comment: That's one of the problems. Mobile users log in within a specific mobile app (and I've got the app id, so we can log them easily). CMS users log in from a shared login page, so their email must be unique

Comment: Ok I see. So would it be fair to say that *admin* level users who manage multiple apps don't need a separate email/password combo per app but users of those apps do?

Comment: That's exactly what happens